# Class Swift_AddressEncoder_IdnAddressEncoder does not exist

Tags: laravel

There is an error occurring in sending mail over mailtrap by a laravel project.I got this error when I uploaded my laravel project on shared hosting. This error doesn't occur while running on the localhost. 
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQjTx.png)

Please help me . I can't find the solution.

Comment: Will be easier if you embed your code and error message in your question instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @Ptaq666 You dont have solution of this error,... same error with me.